# Protocol inheritance from a generic class using associatedType as Type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a quite specific problem and I wasn't able to solve this by the given answers on SO.
To simplify this question, I removed everything that is not needed. This code just shows everything needed to understand the problem:

So I have a class that looks like this:

```
class DataSource<T> {
    
    var data: [T] = []
}
```

Now I want a protocol, that inherits from that class but does not specify the generic (Is this even possible?)

Something like this: (This does not compile but this is the question)

```
protocol Example: DataSource<Item> {
    
    associatedtype Item
    
    func getItems() -> [Item]
}
```

It would be ok, to constrain the generic (e.g. with another protocol). Something like this:

```
protocol Example: DataSource<Item> where Item: Equatable { // or whatever 
        
    associatedtype Item
        
    func getItems() -> [Item]
}
```

I tried in some different ways but none of my ideas worked. Is it possible to specify the generic from the associatedType of the protocol? Do I have to rethink this concept or am I just missing a little detail?

Comment: A protocol can not inherit a class so this is not possible

Comment: Protocols cannot inherit from classes. The syntax you are trying to use only declares that only `DataSource<Item>` subclasses can conform to the `Example` protocol. However, you cannot constrain a protocol to a generic class, since there are no generic protocols. What is it that you are actually trying to do? Also, why use `NSObject` inheritance? This is not Obj-C, classes don't need base classes.

Comment: This is what I can think of but without knowing your goal it's hard to know if it is right `protocol Example where Item: Equatable { associatedtype Item var data: [Item] {get set} func getItems() -> [Item] }`

Comment: @DávidPásztor removed the NSObject inheritance. This is not needed, correct. I am trying to implement a protocol that is required to be a DataSource, as you said. In the real example, DataSource does a lot more than this of course.

Comment: @Teetz as I've said, that is not possible, due to `DataSource` being a generic type. You need to rethink your design to achieve your goals.

Comment: The goal is to let the protocol specifiy (per associatedType) the type of the generic of the DataSource class. But like mentionend I am not sure if this is even possible

Comment: @DávidPásztor Ok. Thanks anyway. If you want to wrap this in a nice little answer I can accept it (if it is not possible it is not possible and this is an answer for me)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you meant this:

```
class DataSource<T> {
    var data: [T] = []
}

protocol Example {
   associatedtype Item
    func getItems() -> [Item]
}

extension DataSource: Example {
    typealias Item = T

    func getItems() -> [T] {
        return self.data
    }
}
```